# Ethernet on Android x86

Tags: android-x86, ethernet

I have recently installed Android x86 on my computer and I am not able to access my internet via Ethernet, I only have Ethernet I don't have any Wi-Fi
Please help me

Comment: What Ethernet chip is on your mainboard? If your chip is not supported by the kernel used by Android x86 it can get complicated to make it work as you have to get the driver source code and build yourself a kernel module. https://groups.google.com/g/android-x86/c/tdp5vy-Ws2Q

Comment: My computer has a RealtekRTL8111 Ethernet chipset
Is that thing supported??